# Where is the best place to store a web service endpoint URI string in an android application?

Tags: android

The Android framework provides us with multiple ways to store data / preferences, where is the best place to store a web service endpoint URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the URI subject to change based on user input and need to persist when the application is closed?  If so, store it in SharedPreferences

Otherwise, you could store it as a static final variable,

You could store it as a resource in strings.xml,

You could store it as a final variable referenced through a subclass of Application, and retrieve it through getApplicationContext().

If you only need it in a single activity, you could just instantiate it when that activity is created.

There's no best option, take your pick.